# SimpleXMLElement - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

In a response we receive an xml file, then convert to SimpleXMLElement, then access the elements and attributes as needed. However, we are getting "Trying to get property of non-object" when xml is loaded directly from string response vs from saved response.

```
//This code works
$response = simplexml_load_file( "response.xml" );
var_dump($response);
echo $response->RESPONSE->RESPONSE_DATA->FILE_INFORMATION['Order_Number'];

//Returns
//object(SimpleXMLElement)#153 (4) { ["@attributes"]=> array(1)...the rest of the xml file...
//Order_Number

//This code returns error
$response = simplexml_load_string( $response );
var_dump($response);
echo $response->RESPONSE->RESPONSE_DATA->FILE_INFORMATION['Order_Number'];

//Returns
//object(SimpleXMLElement)#153 (1) { [0]=> string(33864) "" }
//Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

What would cause the xml to fail when using simplexml_load_string instead of simplexml_load_file?

Here is a snippet of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE_GROUP>
    <RESPONSE>
        <RESPONSE_DATA>
            <FILE_INFORMATION Order_Number="19222835">
                ...
            </FILE_INFORMATION>
        </RESPONSE_DATA>
    </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSE_GROUP>
```

Comment: and your string is well formed? post your string

Comment: Yes, well formed. response.xml equals $response. I would post, but it's 50k lines...

Comment: reduce the lines in the xml and if it works with  simplexml_load_file edit the question with the xml content

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer I saved xml response to dB, and then used simplexml_load_string on that xml response and it works as expected now. I can work with that for now, but still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: the world is strange and mysterious ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php

$response = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RESPONSE_GROUP>
    <RESPONSE>
        <RESPONSE_DATA>
            <FILE_INFORMATION Order_Number="19222835">
                ...
            </FILE_INFORMATION>
        </RESPONSE_DATA>
    </RESPONSE>
</RESPONSE_GROUP>';


//This code returns error
$response = simplexml_load_string( $response );
var_dump($response);
echo $response->RESPONSE->RESPONSE_DATA->FILE_INFORMATION['Order_Number'];


?>
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["RESPONSE"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["RESPONSE_DATA"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["FILE_INFORMATION"]=>
      string(33) "
                ...
            "
    }
  }
}
19222835
```

Answer (score 1):

You've just overlooked a little detail here. It is correct what you say for the first part:

```
$response = simplexml_load_file( "response.xml" );
```

This loads the XML document from the file. However when you look at the second part:

```
$response = simplexml_load_string( $response );
```

You don't load from string response. `$response` represents the **SimpleXMLElement** you've just created from file. The more "correct" example is:

```
$buffer   = file_get_contents( "response.xml" );
$response = simplexml_load_string( $buffer );
```

You perhaps just were confused due to variable-reuse (taken the same named variable for two different things).

And better as `var_dump` is to check with `$response->asXML()` as it will show you the document as XML which shows better what you have (or not).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I didn't specify this, but part 1 and 2 don't run in sequence. I comment out part 1 before trying part 2. It's a strange issue and seems to only be happening to the response of one particular vendor, however the raw string looks fine.

Comment: Then I strongly suggest to not debug with `var_dump` or `print_r` on the  **SimpleXMLElement** but instead to use `$response->asXML('php://output');` to output the actual XML document loaded. That should give you more insight what actually has been loaded.